# How to add a uuid to a rasa chatbot for each user?

Tags: uuid, chatbot, rasa-core

I am developing a chatbot from [this repository](https://github.com/antoinecomp/moodbot4), which I only interconnected with Slack at the moment, and I want him to be able to identify the user. So do you know how to get something online that can generate a unique user identification for each user (the user IDs for the research should have the ability to be stored anonymously) of my chatbot ?

```
from rasa_core.channels import HttpInputChannel
from rasa_core.agent import Agent
from rasa_core.interpreter import RasaNLUInterpreter
from rasa_slack_connector import SlackInput

nlu_interpreter = RasaNLUInterpreter('./models/nlu/default/weathernlu')
agent = Agent.load('./models/dialogue',interpreter = nlu_interpreter)

# https://api.slack.com/apps/AASPDV196/oauth?
input_channel = SlackInput('OAuth Access Token','Bot User OAuth Access Token',
'Verification Token',True)

agent.handle_channel(HttpInputChannel(5004,'/',input_channel))
```

At the moment I am considering wether to :

- use `uuid.uuid4 ()`.
- creating a real web page that registers users with MySQL from [this tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=addnlzdSQs4&index=2&list=PLillGF-RfqbbbPz6GSEM9hLQObuQjNoj_), but I'm not sure it allows Slack.

Slack is not mandatory but, apart from the terminal, I do not have any other Chatbox communication interface at the moment.

Answer (score 0):

By default Rasa Core uses the user name sent by Slack as unique user id. If you want to have some mapping from the Slack user name to some custom id schema, you need to define a [custom channel](https://rasa.com/docs/core/connectors/#creating-a-new-channel) which overwrites the Slack channel. 
I guess the best places to apply your mapping would then be `process_message`, `send_text_message`, `send_image_url`, and `send_attachment`.

If your problem is that the conversations are currently not persisted when you restart Rasa Core, then you might want to look into a different [tracker store](https://rasa.com/docs/core/tracker_stores/) since the default ones stores everything in-memory.